# how to protect "display" page?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to  protect "display" page based on AccessLevel of user who logged in

function protect_page() doesn't work right it access any user with any accesslevel

I use relation between  two tables they are:
privilege table

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |  AccessLevel | login_id  | pre_id|
    |----------------------------------|
    |      1       |    1     |   1    |
    |      2       |    1     |   2    | 
    |      4       |    2     |   4    |
    +----------------------------------+
```

and this is login_pre table:

```
    +----------------------------------+
    |  username| userpass | login_id   |
    |----------------------------------|
    |      a   |    123   |   1        |
    |      a   |    123   |   1        | 
    |      b   |   1234   |   2        |
    +----------------------------------+
```

and the code of privilege page

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\connection\connect.php';
$query ="SELECT * FROM privilege " ;
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');    

             if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
        {  
        $query ="SELECT * FROM privilege where login_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
        $access = $row['AccessLevel'];
            $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];
             echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess'];// output:  1
                }
        }

    ob_end_flush();
```

and code of protect page :

```
include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\login2\privilege.php');

function login()
    {
return (isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid'])) ? true:false ;
echo $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];
    }login();



function privilege()
            {
                return $_SESSION['sessionaccess'];

                }

function protect_page(){
    if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']== true && $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] !=1 ){


header ('location:http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/agtSite/agt2.php');    
//echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess']; output nothing when user a logged in
exit();             
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't tell what is not working.

Comment: function protect_page() doesn't work

Comment: Side note, you should use prepared statements.  If you always use them, you won't run the risk of accidentally forgetting to sanitize user input.

Comment: I edit this but still function doesn't work

Comment: Inside the function, echo out the session variables before the if statement.  What is the output?

Comment: appears A session had already been started

Comment: session output is  12

Comment: sorry I mean session output nothing

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION['sessionaccess']` being set? It doesn't appear to have anything stored in it in the code you've posted.

Comment: sessionaccess in privilege page output 1  but in protect page output nothing

Comment: Not sure how you're getting 1.  It is never set within the code you've shown.

Comment: I test it and output 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be quite a few things to fix, here are a few:

```
//the if statement will only be entered if sessionloginid is set, only set inside the statement, which will never be entered
if(isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid'])) {  
    //you should use prepared statements.  Query will never run here, since the sessionloginid is never set.
    $query ="SELECT * FROM privilege where login_id='".$_SESSION['sessionloginid']."'" ;
    //your login_id used above is not unique.  It should be a key, and autoincremented
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('');
    //since login_id is not unique, this while loop will replace the session variables you will set with the last row returned.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //storing access level, but never used again
        $access = $row['AccessLevel'];
        //the following two lines don't do anything
        $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];
        $_SESSION['sessionaccess'];
        //Example replacement: $_SESSION['sessionloginid'] = $row['login_id'];
    }
}
```

Next issues:

```
function login() {
    //this function will return true or false, but does not set or do anything.  Intentional?
    return (isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid'])) ? true:false ;
    //this echo will not run, since the function stops on return
    echo $_SESSION['sessionloginid'];
}
//calling login here does nothing, since login only returns a Boolean value.
login();
```

The protection will never run header() since the sessionloginid is never set to true, and session access is never set as well.

```
function protect_page(){
  //sessionloginid is never set, so will never be true
  if($_SESSION['sessionloginid']== true && $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] !=1 ){
    header ('location:http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/agtSite/agt2.php');    
    //echo $_SESSION['sessionaccess']; output 12 when user a logged in
    exit();             
  }
}
```

I realize this doesn't completely answer the question, but it should get you headed in the right direction, I hope.  Fix those, and let me know what you get.  Side note:  login_id should be table key, I would think.  It should be autoincremented and unique.  Otherwise you could get multiple results, instead of a unique user logging in.  For example, a login_id of 1 could grant access level of 1 or 2, since there is a login_id of 1 for each of those access levels.